Keyword 'return' in async block
Consider the code
let x =
    async {
        match 1 with
        | 1 -> return 1
     // | 1 -> 1
        | _ -> return! async { return 1 }
    }

Variable x is inferred to be Async<int>, but if the first branch is replaced with the commented code, it does not compile at all.
Why?

In a computation expression, in F#, the return keyword (and return! by extension) is needed to return a non-empty result, otherwise the result will be of type unit. If you comment out your first and last cases and uncomment the second, it will compile but the type will be inferred as Async<unit>, expression 1 will be ignored.

It's a bit like when you write an expression (like 3+1) in a module without anything else, the compiler will warn you that this result will be ignored because it's not unit : this expression is not used (at least according to the compiler, because an expression can have side effects other than returning a result). For the result to be taken into account, you have to return it in the computation expression.

Put simply: this is just how async works.
Whenever you're inside an async block, the last thing you do always has to be a return expression. In other words - if async is a tree, the leaves must always end in return XYZ.

N.B. If you're asking about why it was designed this way (from a language design perspective), it is probably for consistency's sake, and to elucidate what is really going on whenever you use a computation expression. Every operation in an F# computation expression desugars down to method calls (see here). That includes return, which becomes a call to Return(1) (in your case). The same goes for any other operation (especially any keyword ending in ! [bang]). It's a useful way to remember, "oh, something is happening here and the CE is getting involved".
